# Not going through loop / After upload, not removing file

Tags: javascript, cordova

My problem is how to fix my method below and understand why is not working:

The smartphone have 10 audio files. The`LOOP FOR` go through all the audio files and then it goes for the `ft.upload`. Which is wrong, doing 10 times the same 10th audio file(last audio file).
How can I do for the `LOOP FOR` go through the first file and then upload and remove it and keep it looping until the folder is empty? And the `entry.remove(success, fail);` is not removing the file after my file is sucessful uploaded.

Any advices would be helpful.

```
function uploadAudioFiles() {
    var localFolder = "Sounds";
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
        fs.root.getDirectory(localFolder, {create:false}, function(dirEntry){
            var dirReader = dirEntry.createReader();
            dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                    console.log(entries);
                    var entry = entries[i];
                        //print all the audio 1 to 10.
                    var ft = new FileTransfer();
                    if (entry.isFile){
                        var path = entry.fullPath;
                        var name = entry.name;
                //var reader = new FileReader();
                //reader.readAsText(path);
                //print 10x the same audio 10th on success.
                ft.upload(path, "http://111.111.11.1:8080/hello/world/", function(result) {
                    console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                    console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
                    console.log("path:" + path);
                    //it calls success, but is not removing on my smartphone
                    fileSystem.root.getFile(path, {create: false, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                },
                { fileName: name });
            }
        }
    }, fail);
        }, fail);
    });
}

function success(entry) {
    console.log("Removal succeeded" + entry.name + entry.fullPath + entry);
}
function fail(error) {
    alert('Error removing file: ' + error.code);
}
```

Comment: Dude wake up, I'm curious to see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, i was on travel in the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Wrap your upload-call in an anonymous function that you execute immediately with the entry as an argument. This way you "trap" the current value of entry inside the anonymous function. The problem might be that since the uploading of entry is done in a callback function, the value of entry is overwritten in every iteration of the loop. I've had similar problems before and they could be solved like this. I hope I got all brackets right.

```
if (entry.isFile){
    var path = entry.fullPath;
    var name = entry.name;
    (function(currentPath, currentName) {
        ft.upload(currentPath, "http://111.111.11.1:8080/hello/world/", function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            console.log("path:" + currentPath);
            //it calls success, but is not removing on my smartphone
            fileSystem.root.getFile(currentPath, {create: false, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + currentPath + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: currentName });
    })(path, name);
}
```

Comment: Ok, debugged, but still doing the loop because of the ft.upload.

Comment: And somehow it uploaded! What I did was just create another function with ft.upload content and whenever checked if is a file call function with  it. I didn't like my code though. And it's not removing file storage.

Comment: Okay, perhaps you have to do the wrapping a level deeper, just around the ft.upload. I'll edit my post.

Comment: It worked, and I will accept your answer, but still need remove the file that I couldn't do it right.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see anywhere in your code where you remove a file?

Comment: I think it's better to continue here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387188/cordova-removing-file-fails